# Windows 10 keeps shutting down after latest update

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 (see screenshot) keeps shutting down immediately after I enter my login PIN. I updated on Sunday, April 20th, 2018.

I'm using a Dell Inspiron N5110 with an i5 2450M Processor, 8 GB RAM, 1GB NVidia GPU and Samsung 256GB SSD.

Everything ran fine until the update.

Sometimes, I cannot even enter my PIN. It'll shut down even before that.

I ran the Laptop in Safemode and it works fine.

I've attempted repairing the OS but don't have any System Restore Point.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Can't you rollback the version? When I installed the new update, Windows warned me that I could rollback if needed. It will be probably on Settings > System and Restore (if I'm right).

Comment: That update is causing issues for some SSD drives.